# Android Tabs with overlaying / overlapping Image

Tags: android, tabs, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, swipeview

i have a conceptual android question. I use the appcompat library (API min:15, target:21).

And want to place an image over the Top-Tabs (or even within) and the content below. (Content could be a swipeView)

Like this:

[image: Awesome Paint Skills!]

Important is that the image should be fixed within the last tab and laying over the content below. (should be fragment independent)

How would you do it?

Is there something new in Api 21 that can handle this easily?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API 21 will not make this easier. What you can make use of API21 is [ViewOutline](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewOutlineProvider.html) to make your floating action view oval.

However, positioning of the view is likely unrelated to the API version. You need to place the floating button between your tabs holder and content layout. Oval view bottom should be aligned with content and has the bottom margin usually to the half of it's height.